# Selenium WebDriverWait doesn't return all web elements within classes with same name

Tags: java, selenium

Im using this method to retrieve all `src` from `div` classes. For example in the page from my code there are 5 elements, but when I run this code I get only 2 `src`. And if I run my code multiple times, sometimes it returns all of 5 elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "S:\\behance-id\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.behance.net/gallery/148589707/Hercules-and-Randy");
        List<WebElement> firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='ImageElement-root-kir ImageElement-loaded-icR']/img")));
        for (WebElement webElement : firstResult) {
            System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("src"));
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Also tried to add this line, but it didn't help:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

So this script doesn't return all of needed elements even though they are the same class.

Page source code looks like:
[image]

Comment: The elements may not be loaded by that time you try to get the lements. Try waiting for few seconds

Comment: I increased timeout to 30 seconds - it didn't help. Timeout has no effect in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
```

Above is for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page and will break as soon as it find one, it will not wait for 5 elements.It returns true as soon as elements.size>0

You need to add to some other wait to make sure all elements are loaded before you do findelements

Below will wait for count of elements be 5

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                int elementCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xxxx")).size();
                if (elementCount == 5)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });
```